# Update Column Range with the cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have an input sheet called "Testfall-Input-Vorschlag where we have to choose a value from a dropdown in the cells of the first row from the 7th (J)column and when a value gets chosen for example "ARB13" I want to fill out the column where it is selected. The filling of the column is with random values. There is a Sheet called "Admin" which has values stored in the cells of columns from A:ZZ. Now I in the "Testfall-Input-Vorschlag" sheet I want to fill out the cells of the column sequentially. Which means for example for cell(11,7) i want to generate a random value from column A in "Admin" for cell (12,7) the value has to be from Column B in "Admin" for cell (13,7) the value is from column C in "Admin and so on. So I have been trying  and I've come up with this code

```
Sub ARB13()


Dim col As Integer


For i = 11 To 382


For j = 7 To 1000


If Sheets("Testfall-Input_Vorschlag").Cells(1, j) = "ARB13" Then
col = 0
col = col + 1
 LB = 2
    UB = Sheets("Admin").Range("col" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(i, j).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Sheets("Admin").Range("Y" & Int((UB - LB + 1) *       Rnd + LB))


 End If
 Next j
 Next i
 End Sub
```

How can I update the col value for every i. Which means for every i I need col value to be increased by 1. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: one item `Range("col" & Rows.Count)` should be using Cells() instead `Cells(Rows.Count,col)`

Answer (score 0):

Define `col` before you start your first loop, and don't put `col = col + 1` in the `For j = 7 to 1000` loop. Otherwise `col` will increment for every `j` instead of every `i`. Something like this:

```
Sub ARB13()
    Dim col as Long
    Dim i  as Long
    Dim j as Long

    col = 0

    For i = 11 To 382
        For j = 7 to 1000
            LB = 2
            UB = Sheets("Admin").Cells(Rows.count, col).End(xlUp).row
            Cells(i, j).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Sheets("Admin").Range("Y" & Int((UB - LB + 1) * Rnd + LB))
        Next j

        col = col +1
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Range("col" & Rows.count).` Is not proper, unless the OP wants column COL.  But I think he wants the value of the variable `col`.  Also the formula may need a little work.